# Getting module not found error for crypto, fs.. while initializing mongoClient in the Constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my api.ts file for connecting to MongoDb,which I am using to get the data from services collection and store it in a result.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongo-client';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class mongoConnection {
    constructor(private mongoClient: MongoClient) { }

    getConnection() {
        let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

        this.mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let dbo = db.db("mycustomers");
            dbo.collection("services").find({}), function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;

                console.log(result);
                db.close();
                return result;
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the services.component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Options } from 'ng5-slider';

import {mongoConnection} from '../api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { trigger, style, transition, animate, keyframes, query, stagger } from '@angular/animations';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Item } from '../Item';
import { Bus } from '../Bus';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-services',
  templateUrl: './services.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services.component.css'],

    export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit {

    buses$: Object;

     services:string;
            buses=[];

      constructor(private data: DataService, private data1: mongoConnection) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.services= this.data1.getConnection();

        this.data.getBuses().subscribe(
          (data => this.buses$ = data)
        )
       }
    }
```

I am unable to build the project, buliding it is producing below errors.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/bson' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './win32/ia32/bson' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './win32/x64/bson' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/bson/ext'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands/db_command.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/commands'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/pavan/Desktop/apstrtcAngular/node_modules/mongo-client/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs'
```

Below is also my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "apstrtc-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.0.0",
    "body-parse": "^0.1.0",
    "bson": "^3.0.2",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "mongo-client": "^0.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.9",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.11",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.1.4",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "router": "^1.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I was able to connect to mongoDb using a .js file, but I was not able to forward the data from that js file to the component. Since I am very new to angular, I would be glad if there is any other easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the right answer, but after some research I belive that  ServerModules like
MongoDb, mongoose etc should not be imported into the clientSide, Since Angular is completely ClientSide, i think mongoose should not be imported into the component.